How can I control the placement of tables in scrbook class documents?
I am creating a document with scrbook document class. In this document, I want to keep the tables exactly where I create it. I use float package for this. My intention is to use the [H] placement option from the float package. I have tried two ways so far. First, I put the following lines in the preamble
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{table}[H]

The second way was to put
AtBeginDocument{%
  \floatplacement{table}{H}
}

But in both the cases, I am getting the same error:
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

Is there any other way to keep the table where I create it, in scrbook document class?

You can't use H in floatplacement it needs to be on the environment and makes it not a float (it's simpler just to not use figure at all, the only reason to use figure is to allow the image to float and the only reason to use [H] is to stop the figure floating)

Note, that KOMA-Script classes already provide non-floating environments for figures and tables. See section 3.20 in the current KOMA-Script manuals. Additionally they provide \captionof for alternative solutions.

you wouldn't get the error shown from the second version assuming you have a \  in \AtBeginDocument

@cabohah ooh I don't think I'd noticed that before, figure-  You could make an answer as that's clearly more relevant here than a standard "how to use [H] " answer.

@cabohah oh you just did:-) +1

\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Tables without float}
\KOMAScript{} classes provide environments \texttt{table-} and \texttt{figure-}
for non-floating tables and figures, e.g., the table
\begin{table-}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    left & center & right
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Demonstration table}
\end{table-}
does not float.

They also provide command \verb`\captionof` and therefore the table:
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    left & center & right
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{table}{Almost same again}
\end{center}
also does not float.
\end{document}


For more information please see the KOMA-Script manuals.
The two environments table- and figure- need at least KOMA-Script v3.36 2022/05/01. \captionof is already provided for decades.

Thank you for solving my problem instantly.
