How to place the Figure in the Exact Position where we wish in a LaTeX document?
For a new book I am working, which is in the Final Submission Stage, the Publisher has asked us to place the Figures in the Examples, as soon as they start. For example, if I include a Figure as part of a Problem, the Publisher would like the Figure to appear as soon as the Problem ends, and the Solution begins. Unfortunately, the Figure comes on the next page in the output (PDF) file, and I don't know how to do it. My query is: How to place the Figure in the Exact Position where we wish in a LaTeX document? Can this be achieved with the help of any special package? Thank you for great help!

Don't put it in a figure environment. A figure is a float. You are telling LaTeX to move it to the 'best position'. You don't want that, so don't tell LaTeX to do that. And please don't add arbitrary tags to questions.

If not figure, how to insert it? Will \includegraphics work if I do it between Problem and Solution? In this case, I may not be able to generate the "List of Figures".. We may have to do it manually, I guess.. Around 20 Figures in the book, thanks!

Yes, it will work. You can use the caption or capt-of (?) package which provide \captionof to use when you need a caption outside a float. You might also want something like a center environment as figure adds some vertical space. (The capt-of package, if I've got the name right, just provides this. caption is good if you want its other features.)

Possible duplicate: Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned

Thank you, I shall try.. Only downside is - \listoffigures cannot be generated without Figure environment. I plan to prepare this in a Word document (with page numbers of Figures) and send to my Publisher next week..

@Dr.Sundar It is the caption which generates the entry in the list - not the environment. Just use one of those packages.

@cfr OK, you give great ideas, I shall try - Thanks

@Werner It's not really a duplicate of that question, but surely there must be a different one. But there is an answer which matches, though it doesn't give an example or explain a package is needed.

And please note, that an answer can also depend on the used class (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/716269/277964). So once again a minimal working example could be helpful to help you.

Don't use a float as floats tell LaTeX to move the contents to the 'best position'. Instead, use \captionof from the capt-of or caption package and a center environment or similar to compensate for the loss of figure's vertical spacing. The example demonstrates this works fine generating a list of figures, but I can't make decent images right now due to an Okular-on-X bug.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{center}\includegraphics{example-image-a}\par\captionof{figure}{A figure.}\end{center}
\begin{center}\includegraphics{example-image-b}\par\captionof{figure}{A figure.}\end{center}
\begin{center}\includegraphics{example-image-c}\par\captionof{figure}{A figure.}\end{center}
\end{document}



Can this be achieved with the help of any special package?

So, if I understand the issue, the Publisher wants to keep all three elements together in this order: problem, image, and solution. It's not clear to me if the whole block should appear in the PDF as a float or be placed exactly as requested in texts, between specific paragraphs. Here, I assumed the former, that is ProblemSolution is a float. That means LaTeX will placed problem-solution blocks exactly the same way as images inside figure environment, as a float, however all three elements always be grouped togethere.
You could achieve your goal by just placing everything in the figure environment. However, float package is very handy here due to a few additions (see the example below.) For instance \caption will use a custom label, you can make a list of custom floats, you can style the float etc. The most important macro is \newfloat. It creates a custom environment, then everything inside will be move around exactly the same way as other standard floats are.
In the example, please note where exactly ProblemsSolution environments are placed in text and where they appear in the PDF. For instance, the first Problem is placed after the first paragraph, yet it appears at the top of the very next page in PDF because LaTeX does not find enough space. The second and the third ProblemSolution appear in the PDF as requested because now there is enough space for them. In all three instances, everything is still grouped together.
The example:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newfloat{problem}{tbhp}{psf}[chapter]
\floatname{problem}{Problem}
\newenvironment{ProblemSolution}{%
  \begin{problem}
    \noindent\leftskip=2cm\rightskip=2cm\small
}{\end{problem}}
\captionsetup[problem]{font=small,labelfont=bf,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-4cm}%


% \usepackage{showframe}
% \renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
% \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}

\title{The Title}
\author{First Last}
\date{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\listof{problem}{List of Problems}

\chapter{First one}
First paragraph.
\kant[1]

\begin{ProblemSolution}
  \paragraph{Problem:}
  Some notes about a problem that should be a little longer and span multiple lines.

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth,height=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption about the first problem}
  \end{center}

  \paragraph{Solution:}
  Something about solution.
\end{ProblemSolution}

Second paragraph.
\kant[2]

Third paragraph.
\kant[3]

Fourth paragraph.
\kant[4]

\begin{ProblemSolution}
  \paragraph{Problem:}
  Some notes about a problem that should be a little longer and span multiple lines.

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth,height=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption about the second problem}
  \end{center}

  \paragraph{Solution:}
  Something about solution.
\end{ProblemSolution}


\chapter{Second two}
Fifth paragraph.
\kant[5-6]

\begin{ProblemSolution}
  \paragraph{Problem:}
  Some notes about a problem that should be a little longer and span multiple lines.

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth,height=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Caption about the third problem}
  \end{center}

  \paragraph{Solution:}
  Something about solution.
\end{ProblemSolution}

Sixth paragraph.
\kant[7]
\end{document}


